# IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "System::Net::WebHeaderCollection::set" matches the argument list

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

When attempting to set a key using the square bracket syntax...

```
request->Headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip, deflate";
```

I receive the following error:

```
IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "System::Net::WebHeaderCollection::set" matches the argument list
        argument types are: (const char [16], const char [14])
        object type is: System::Net::WebHeaderCollection ^
```

When explicitly passing in `String^` params...

```
request->Headers[gcnew String("Accept-Encoding")] = gcnew String("gzip, deflate");
```

I get:

```
IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "System::Net::WebHeaderCollection::set" matches the argument list
        argument types are: (System::String ^, System::String ^)
        object type is: System::Net::WebHeaderCollection ^
```

However,

```
request->Headers->Set("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
```

Works fine. So what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three versions of your code can compile and run, so this just looks like an Intellisense bug. I can reproduce it in any class with an overloaded indexer whose setters can take either an Int32 or a String^ index parameter. I've found Intellisense to be pretty flaky in C++/CLI, so this is probably the first of many warts you'll find.

Consider reporting the issue to https://connect.microsoft.com/